C# zodiac sign using array and if else statement
I created a program using C#. It's a Zodiac Sign Identifier using arrays and if-else statements because the task only allows the use of arrays and if-else statements. The code's logic is that it stores the zodiac signs, months, and days in arrays. Then, by using if-else statements, it determines the user's zodiac sign.
Aries (March 21 – April 19)
Taurus (April 20 – May 20)
Gemini (May 21 – June 20)
Cancer (June 21 – July 22)
Leo (July 23 – August 22)
Virgo (August 23 – September 22)
Libra (September 23 – October 22)
Scorpio (October 23 – November 21)
Sagittarius (November 22 – December 21)
Capricorn (December 22 – January 19)
Aquarius (January 20 – February 18)
Pisces (February 19 – March 20)

My code is:
        Console.WriteLine("ZODIAC SIGN");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        string[] zodiacsign = { "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius"};  

        int[] signmonth = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }; 
        int[] signday = { 20, 19, 21, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22 }; 

        Console.Write("Enter the month (1 to 12): ");
        int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.Write("Enter the day: ");
        int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");

        string zodiacSign;

        
        if ((month == 1 && day >= 20) || (month == 2 && day < 19))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[0]; // Capricorn
        }
        else if ((month == 2 && day >= 19) || (month == 3 && day < 21))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[1]; // Aquarius
        }
        else if ((month == 3 && day >= 21) || (month == 4 && day < 20))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[2]; // Pisces
        }
        else if ((month == 4 && day >= 20) || (month == 5 && day < 21))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[3]; // Aries
        }
        else if ((month == 5 && day >= 21) || (month == 6 && day < 21))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[4]; // Taurus
        }
        else if ((month == 6 && day >= 21) || (month == 7 && day < 23))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[5]; // Gemini
        }
        else if ((month == 7 && day >= 23) || (month == 8 && day < 23))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[6]; // Cancer
        }
        else if ((month == 8 && day >= 23) || (month == 9 && day < 23))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[7]; // Leo
        }
        else if ((month == 9 && day >= 23) || (month == 10 && day < 23))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[8]; // Virgo
        }
        else if ((month == 10 && day >= 23) || (month == 11 && day < 22))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[9]; // Libra
        }
        else if ((month == 11 && day >= 22) || (month == 12 && day < 22))
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[10]; // Scorpio
        }
        else
        {
            zodiacSign = zodiacsign[11]; // Sagittarius
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Your zodiac sign is {zodiacSign}.");

        Console.ReadLine();

I try the code using the Month as 7 (July) and 5 as day but the output is GEMINI instead of CANCER
Here is the example of the output:
ZODIAC SIGN
Enter the month (1 to 12): 7
Enter the day: 2
Your zodiac sign is Gemini.
Can you help me solve this problem if ever can you simply the code by using Array and If else Statement only Thank You

Well your conditions for Gemini is if ((month == 6 && day >= 21) || (month == 7 && day < 23)). Month is 7 and 2 is < 23 so that's what it selects.

What do i need to change inorder for it to run smoothly

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? and How to debug small programs

Go through all your conditions and check that they're correct. For example, the first condition says that Capricorn is from Jan 20th to Feb 18th. Is that correct? If not, change it so that it chooses the correct one instead. Then move on to the next one.

It would be nicer to make the thing table driven with a for loop to check through the list of zodiac signs start and end dates (or better held as a struct). It is dangerous to have two distinct representations of the same data in different locations - they invariably end up out of step after a while even if they are right at first. As it is all your star signs in the if statements are shifted along by one and Ophiuchus is missing...

Code smell: you have a signmonth and signday, but you never seem to use them

I think that you have to correct is the order of the array, so change it from:
string[] zodiacsign = { "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius"};

to
string[] zodiacsign = { "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio","Sagittarius" ,"Capricorn"};

because Capricorn is between December 22nd and January 20th, and
Sagittarius is between November 22nd and December 21st. Seeing a little bit fast, but the position of "Capricorn" is not correct in the array, if that's your problem.

“Seeing a little bit fast”?
